# $array[] and array_push not working

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I'm testing out a simple redemption system and it's not working.
When a user enters a valid code, it doesn't add it to the 'used' array.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$code   = $_POST['code'];

$used = array(
    "swig",
    "sworgle"
);

$valid = array(
    "swug",
    "sweggle"
);

if($submit){

if(in_array($code, $valid)){
    if(!in_array($code, $used)){
    echo "Congratulations! That is a correct code. <a href='index.php'>Click here to go back</a>";
    $used[] = $code;
} elseif(in_array($code, $used))
    echo "This code has already been used. <a href='index.php'>Click here to go back</a>";
} elseif(!in_array($code, $valid))
    echo "This code is invalid <a href='index.php'>Click here to go back</a>.";

}
else
    echo "Nice try. <a href='index.php'>Go back</a>.";

?>
```

I've tried array_push($used, $code); but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Don't you need to save `$used` somewhere?

Comment: What? [random words here because all comments have to have 15 or more characters]

Comment: what show after add `var_dump($used);` in the end of file

Comment: You're adding something to `$used` in your code. You say it's the full code; but there's nothing to save the value of the array once the code is finished. So the next time the code is run, you'll have exactly the same two codes in `$used` again.

Comment: When I put var_dump($used);, it showed that the code was entered into the array, but it wasn't.

Comment: @andrewsi How do I fix it then?

Comment: @WillMacklemore - I'd suggest using a database to store codes, and updating it when they're used. You can also use text files for this sort of thing, which is less complex than databases.

Comment: In addition to what @andrewsi has pointed out, I would say you also need to generally need to gain an understanding for how to maintain state in a web application, as this is generally what you are trying to do.  Without maintaining state in some manner, your script will remain stateless, in this case, re-defining the value for `$used` array with each request against the script.

Comment: I've put $used in used.php, $valid in valid.php and I've included both of the files. I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be that the code you're going through parameters already in the array, I recommend you make the variable print **$code**.